# Pressing 'enter' with multiple input boxes

Tags: input, enter

I have an HTML form with several input boxes and their corresponding enter button. When I type something in the first input box and either press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or the button, it works fine. But if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the other boxes it works as if it was in the first box. The buttons work OK.

Here is the code I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function fn (num) {
    alert(num);
    document.getElementById(num).focus();
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
  <input id="1" type="text"></input> <button onclick="fn(1);">press</button><br/>
  <input id="2" type="text"></input> <button onclick="fn(2);">press</button><br/>
  <input id="3" type="text"></input> <button onclick="fn(3);">press</button><br/>
</form>
```

Apparently this is a 'quirk' in ECMA (I have tested in FF18.0.1 and Safari 5.1.7).
Is there a fix for this quirk?

One solution that I found is to add one form per input box.

```
<form>
  <input id="1" type="text"></input> <button onclick="fn(1);">press</button><br/>
</form>
<form>
  <input id="2" type="text"></input> <button onclick="fn(2);">press</button><br/>
</form>
<form>
  <input id="3" type="text"></input> <button onclick="fn(3);">press</button><br/>
</form>
```

Is this a bug or a feature? Is there a better solution? 
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: It's a feature. Or call it a design flaw; not a bug. Buttons don't "correspond" to input boxes. So there can be only one button per form that responds to the Enter key. No matter what textbox you're in. So you've already got the answer, and I don't believe there's a better one.

Comment: No, the problem is not with the buttons but with the input boxes, so your answer misses the point completely. If I have the focus on an input box and press enter, it should do something about that input box, not about a different one. Thanks but no thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use onKeyPress instead of onClick.  Try this:

```
function myKeyPress(args) {
  if ((e.which && e.which == 13) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 13)) {
    // do something here (enter has been pressed)
  }
  else {
    return false; // somehow prevents "default" form behaviors
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("id").keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        respective functions
    }
});
```

or

```
 <input type="text" name="q" id="q" 
        onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {call function}" />
```