# input vs .net texbox: input clears on enter pressed, asp:textbox does not

Tags: asp.net

I use the jquery datepicker. I have the following input in the updatePanel:

```
  <input id="DateMask" type="text" />
```

and js code:

```
  $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true
                });

  $(document).ready(function () {
     SetD();
  });
```

Using jQuery:

```
  <script src="/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/scripts/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When I press enter on my page it clears my input, and I do not post anything to the server. I've managed to solve the problem by writing `<asp:textbox>` instead of `<input>`, but why is it so?

[and found the topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447821/pressing-enter-with-multiple-input-boxes)

But once again why does it work this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to the difference between 'standard' HTML controls, and .NET server controls.

When you use a standard HTML `<input>` in .net, you are in charge of everything relating to it - quite simply, population of the initial value and later retrieval through Request.Form.

The advantage that the server controls - including, as you've noticed, `<asp:textbox>` - bring is that the ASP.Net framework now handles most of the messy parts for you. Thus, any text that you enter is available in the code-behind as a property of the object, and when control returns back to the page the textbox is re-populated with the same value it had beforehand.

I'd suggest having a read of a few background topics that discuss this, primarily the ASP.Net server controls overview at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306459.